# i need a regex that cares for order and other general requirements

Tags: python, regex

I have been searching a lot through the net and couldn't find a regex that cares for order and other general requirements, my specific need is the following:

1. Starts with a letter;
2. At least 6 characters;
3. At least 1 digit.

I'm working in python, I think I know how to write the regex for 2&3 but didn't find a way to combine 1 since it involves order. 
Similarly, I know how to write 1 but didn't find a way to combine it with general requirements regex (meaning brackets regex... don't know the name)

For 2 and 3:

```
^(?=.{6,})(?=.*[\d]).*$
```

For 1:

```
^[a-zA-Z].*
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: post sample input and output. post your so far work.

Comment: So something like `A----1` would suffice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A general technique to build a "conjunctive" expression that matches A *and* B *and* C is to start with `^` and then list conditions as lookahead groups:

```
^(?=A)(?=B)(?=C)
```

In your case:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z])(?=.{6,})(?=\D*\d)
```

As to the question why this expr doesn't work with `$`:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z])(?=.{6,})(?=\D*\d)$
```

this is because it doesn't consume any characters, except the virtual "start of input". When you append a `$` to it, it becomes equivalent to `^$`, which can only match an empty string.

Comment: *im willing to accept every english letter.
*what's \D ?
*does that care for the order? as i said, i need the first char to be an english letter

Comment: What do you mean by "care for the order"? This expr matches only strings that start with letters.

Comment: ok it worked after i erased the $ sign.
can you please explain that?

does the spot where a (...) matters? (i guess it does) ans whats \D

Comment: @user1413824 - what $ sign? Are you are using the regex from another answer?

Comment: `\D` is a non-digit. It's rather a minor optimization here, a simple dot would work just as well.

Comment: i don't understand, on the one hand, i conclude that the position of (?=[A-Za-z]) is important, but on the other hand, there is the expression (?=.{6,}) which probably can be placed everywhere. I can't understand the rule here..

Comment: ok. so so lets say i want that the second char would be a letter and i dont care for the first char. how would you modify the regex?

Comment: @user1413824: try to think about this in terms of the caret (`^`). The second char is a letter means you're looking for the caret following by any symbol and a letter. So, `^(?=.[a-z])`.

Comment: Ok i think i understand how the conditions work now. So lets say i want the 3rd char to be a letter, would the condition be ^(?=.{2,2}[a-z])    ?

Comment: @user1413824: yes, though I'd use `.{2}` or just `..`

Answer (score 4):

> my specific need is the following:
>
> - Starts with a letter;
> - More than 6 characters;
> - At least 1 digit.

Never mind regexes then. Test for the properties you want directly.

```
len(x) > 6 and x[0].isalpha() and any(c.isdigit() for c in x)
```

Comment: This will fail with an `IndexError` on `''` (I dealt with that in my similar but more complete answer).

Comment: @Chris Morgan No; that's why I put the `len` test first.

Answer (score 1):

Start by not assuming that regular expressions are the solution. Then think about the other tools that are available.

Starts with a letter:

```
word and word[0].isalpha()
```

(If this test goes after the length one, the `word and` bit can be dropped.)

At least six characters long:

```
len(word) >= 6
```

At least one digit:

```
any(letter.isdigit() for letter in word)
```

This last one is `O(n)` for the length of word, though, and if you go for twenty characters without a number it actually ends up slower than the RE solution, because of the string instantiation; you can counter that if long strings with no early numbers will occur regularly with this rather long-winded version:

```
('0' in word or '1' in word or '2' in word or '3' in word or
'4' in word or '5' in word or '6' in word or '7' in word or
'8' in word or '9' in word)
```

You can then combine these with ease. Remember with things like this to put it in a separate function with an appropriate docstring; don't put magic calculations in the midst of other unrelated things.

```
def word_rule_check(word):
    '''
    Check that the word complies to Rule such-and-such; it must:

    1. start with a letter,
    2. be at least 6 characters long, and
    3. contain at least one digit.
    '''

    return (len(word) >= 6 and
            word[0].isalpha() and
            any(letter.isdigit() for letter in word))
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He wants a regex. It's probably a homework question.

Comment: @mhawke: strictly, I have indeed not answered the *question*. But would you deny that this is a better solution to his *problem*?

Comment: It is a better solution to the _general_ problem :) It is probably not a solution to _his_ problem if he requires a regex.

Comment: I strongly doubt that he requires a regular expression. It's just the standard thing to think you should do it with a regular expression, without actually thinking about whether it's the best solution.

Comment: ... or a regex is required because it will be used in an existing regex based validator (or it's a home work question).

Answer (score 0):

`^(?=.{6,})[a-zA-Z].*\d.*$` is what you need.

Comment: Consider something like `a--123`.

Comment: @thg435: ok. so the letter can be anything.`^(?=.{6,})[a-zA-Z]+\d.*$`

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: sorry, I was indeed thinking incorrectly by then; I was thinking that `\w` didn't include digits. But @thg435 is correct and shows what I was going to say next, that non-alnum chars wouldn't be done. `.` is better than `\w`. In this case, I don't see why you'd bother with the `.*$` part. It's easier to omit it; it serves no value. Also, you still don't cope with `a--123`

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: updated. Again i considered letters as alphabets,not symbols.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley: he says *characters*, not *letters*. You should be matching `a--123`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't very effective at measuring length, just use python `len()` for that.
As for the other two conditions, try this:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*
```